# Не получается установить модуль src в Pycharm

Tags: python, модули, pytest

[image][image: Г]
Учу pytest, и сделал все по уроку, но выдает ошибку модулей, что делать? Если вы скажите что в global_enums.py я написал from enum а не enums то это тоже не помогает

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120)